# C++ "'DOMDocument' : redefinition" Error with Xercesc

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files, msxml, xerces

My problem is that Xerces and Windows both have a `'DOMDocument'` object. Xerces and just about everything I've read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/e189173e-870d-440b-a416-340678481ed7), [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/faq-build-3.html) and [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xerces-c-users/200506.mbox/%3C6.2.1.2.2.20050615175705.05185ae0@webmail.bedford.progress.com%3E) has suggested to define the namespace or undefine `DOMDocument` which should look something like this.

```
Void foo(XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE::DOMDocument* pDocument);
```

or

```
#undef DOMDocument
#include <xerces/Stuff>
```

I wanted to go the sane route and just apply the namespace but it doesn't seem to work. I'm really hesitant to use an `#undef` that feels like hacking around the problem.

The windows file `msxml.h` is the one that's complaining about a redefinition.

Could this have to do with the order they are loaded? I have something like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include "XMLClass.h"
```

Where `XMLClass.h` includes xerces headers. It's really hard to tell whats causing the issue because the error shows up in a microsoft header.

I've also searched for `'DOMDocument'` in the whole project and everywhere I use `'DOMDocument'` has a namespace of `XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE`.

**Note:** I'm using xerces 3.1 and VS 2010.

Ideas?

**Update:**
I have tried `#undef` before adding the xerces headers and I'm still receiving the error. So I'm really at a lost as to why both solutions aren't working for me.

**Update 2:**
I've also tried changing the namespace from `XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE::DOMDocument` to `xercesc::DOMDocument` but this has not helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a header load order problem.

There are 2 libraries I'm aware of that include `msxml.h` somewhere inside their code,

```
#include<Windows.h>
```

and

```
#include<ole2.h>
```

In my case `#include <Windows.h>` happened to be down stream of my `#include "XMLClass.h"`. So the solution was to define `msxml.h` before `xerces` like this,

```
#include<msxml.h>             //defines DOMDocument first     
//defines DOMDocument with a different namespace
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMDocument.hpp>
```

Because `xerces` was mindful of namespaces and Microsoft wasn't, if the headers are defined in reverse order like this,

```
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMDocument.hpp>
#include<msxml.h>
```

no matter what you do your code will not compile. The compiler will tell you that you are redefining `'DOMDocument'`, which is actually whats happening. This is because of the way Microsoft wrote `msxml.h`.

Hope this helps anyone bumping into this problem.

**Note:**

you must ALWAYS include the namespace when defining 'DOMDocument' objects, parameters and return types like this,

```
XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE::DOMDocument xmlDoc;

void setDoc(XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE::DOMDocument xmlDoc);

XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE::DOMDocument getDoc();
```

or you will continue to receive ambiguity errors or **worst** it will assume the wrong data-type at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar problem where one definition was coming from mshtml.h file and another from xercesc.
There were three classes i was using 
"DOMDocumentType"
"DOMException"
"DOMProcessingInstruction"

and after changing the order it worked

Thanks